# 3ds animation on android

Tags: java, android, 3d, 3ds

I'm struggling to find a way to load a 3d model/animation on Android.

I know min3d framework and I would like to create a sample 3d animation, like a level, and running it on android.

Min3D is supporting really well the md2 files but I don't know really how to edit md2s.
Is there any way to load 3ds animations even not using min3d? if not, is there an alternative way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free library that should get you started:

```
http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/index.html
```